# 7z getting an event not found error in command line

Tags: bash, shell, quoting

I am using 7zip on my centos machine and ziping a file via command line.

This is my syntax

```
7za a -t7z backup.7z public_html\ -mx0 -xr!restricted_area
```

What i'm expecting with this syntax is to backup all files in public_html folder then exclude restricted_area folder, I am not really sure if this is correct, but the problem is I am getting this error:

```
-bash: !restricted_area: event not found
```

What does this suppose to mean? And also, Is my zipping syntax correct?

Comment: Escape the `!`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`!` begins a shell history expansion. In particular, `!foo` expands to the last command you wrote that begins with `foo`. As you don't have any commands in your history that begin with `restricted_area`, bash is giving you an error. You can get around this by escaping or quoting the `!`:

```
7za ... -xr\!restr...
7za ... -xr'!'restr...
7za ... '-xr!restr...'
```

For more information, see the bash man page under History Expansion -> Event Designators.

Comment: If I want to exclude other directories, should I just repeat the -xr\! and replace the 'restricted_area' into the directory that i want to exclude?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the 7zip syntax, but if you have more `!`s, you will need to escape them as well.